# Emulating Ajax request via Scrapy - Can't decode unicode response

Tags: python, ajax, python-3.x, encoding, scrapy

I am succesfully emulating Ajax requests in my code, here is part of the exact response I am getting (written to file/printed to console)

> \u003ctr\u003e\u003ctd class=\"box_pro_high1\"  style=\"width:166px;height:302px;\"\u003e\r\n  \u003cdiv  align=\"center\"\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv style=\"width:160px;height:100px;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;\"\u003e\r\n      \u003ca href=\"/antennas-connectors-accessories/adaptors-connectors/sma-r-a-8906/sma390-8153/pd/\" rel=\"pd.aspx?\u0026amp;pid=8153\u0026amp;fid=8906\u0026amp;cid=WES1863229926N\u0026amp;pcr=WES596880305N\u0026amp;Path=hJhp9Eo4i4SmypehwrGDk1dSIV1a%2fzDdQ39QdmWB6NLz%2bOfhVWXfF%2buXHGazJfLb25nPLAnzP5cA1EMeQ6IUDQMZmGxNYGTr8ARSiPUbiPN8GaSYHamQH9%2bSCQaRu3yY8Nv8%2fB75yy4UdDKkWwfIpY9zTNKSLx0anQ%2fNUrFOtGvph5cABhGlLBWHi%2fFJQEXw4P9%2bLdS%2fn1Q%3d\"  class=\"tx_3\"\u003e\r\n       \r\n        \u003cimg data-original=\"/prodimages/section7_th/sma390.jpg\" style=\"max-height:100px; max-width:100px;\" border=\"0\" alt=\"SMA390 SMA R/A\"  class=\"lazy\" src=\"\"/\u003e\r\n      \u003c/a\u003e\r\n    \u003c/div\u003e\r\n    \u003cdiv class=\"familyheader\" style=\"height:30px;\"\u003e\r\n \r\n      \u003ca href=\"/antennas-connectors-accessories/adaptors-connectors/sma-r-a-8906/sma390-8153/pd/\"

I am trying to pass it to BeautifulSoup/lxml but it (understandably) fails.

Via simple google search I have found this site: http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php

that "decodes" (I am not sure it's correct term) this string with one click to:

```
    <img data-original="/prodimages/section7_th/sma390.jpg" style="max-height:100px; max-width:100px;" border="0" alt="SMA390 SMA R/A"  class="lazy" src=""/>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="familyheader" style="height:30px;">

  <a href="/antennas-connectors-accessories/adaptors-connectors/sma-r-a-8906/sma390-8153/pd/"
```

Which is exactly what I want. But I can't emulate this behavior in python.

I have tried using ord(), decode(), etc. but can't seem to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is unicode escaped strings, you can simply turn it into readable html:

```
s = "\u003ctr\u003e\u003c ......."
s = s.decode('unicode-escape')
```

Now you can treat the `s` string as the correct response to use with beautifulsoup or scrapy's selectors.

for python3 is even simpler

```
s = str.encode(s)
```

Comment: Unfortunetely it isn't. It is str with unicode characters. Your solution raises:

'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: sorry, I wasn't thinking it was for python3, please check the updated answer

Comment: I have no idea why, but this is what finally worked for me: `s.encode().decode('unicode-escape')`